# How can i know total number of sends from each BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

My goal is create a Data Extension in the Parent BU with a column for my 5 BUs  where the record will populate by the total number of sent last 30 days from each BU i have.

I utilize only a sender profile if it's help anyone to know how i can do this.

I thinks i can SQL, but how can i segment for each BU?

**EDIT**: I tried to used this sintax below, but the same number goes to all fields. How i can solved this?

My thought the arquitecture it's like the image attached

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN AccountID ='100000001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [PARENT_BU], 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN AccountID = '100000002' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BU1],
COUNT(CASE WHEN AccountID = '100000003' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BU2],
COUNT(CASE WHEN AccountID = '100000004' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BU3],
DATENAME(month, PickupTime) AS [MONTH]
FROM _Job
WHERE PickupTime BETWEEN GETDATE()-38 AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, PickupTime)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an automation on your top level business unit using the Data View: Sent

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5

Let's say for this example, you have 3 business units.

- 10000001 <-- Parent BU
- 10000002 <-- Child BU
- 10000003 <-- Child BU

You can use the following SQL below to accomplish what you are needing.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.AccountID = 10000001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10000001]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.AccountID = 10000001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10000002]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.AccountID = 10000001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10000003]
      ,DATENAME(month, s.EventDate) AS [Month]
FROM _Sent AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE s.EventDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())), 0)
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, s.EventDate)
```

**Data Views contain 6 months worth of data. I added a function in the WHERE clause to only get data from the past 2 months, max. This way, you sent summary does not get overwritten by data that drops off of the view**

Comment: Hello, @Spencer. So thanks for your help and understand the sintax. But i have a problem with the WHERE clause: "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

What you think to solve this?

Comment: Move the GROUP BY expression to the end of the query. That should resolve your problem

Comment: Great catch, @RachidMamai. I've made that edit.

Comment: @SpencerCurtis, RachidMamais, unfortunately, it's not working, not populated the DE. I tried to use Count(Case WHEN..) and change Event Date and the only changes that happen it's the same number for the all fields.